# Cannot instance AGConnectFunction

Tags: java, android, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect, agconnect-functions

I'm referring to this code lab here: [Cloud Functions for Android](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/CloudFunctions/index.html#3)

```
apply plugin:'com.huawei.agconnect' 
...
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-function:1.4.1.300'
}
```

Besides that "configure the following address" appears to be a wrongful CN to EN translation
and that I'm using the current version `1.6.0.300` instead; the IDE gives me these imports:

[image]

---

Please don't close for requesting a library; because it is "simply not there" (see the screenshot), despite the AAR is being located at: `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.huawei.agconnect/agconnect-function/1.6.0.300/ed356f3bc516e39734b8a6b1dd7ec9a680d3bffd/agconnect-function-1.6.0.300.aar` and can be extracted, from which I know for certain that it should be called:

```
import com.huawei.agconnect.function.AGConnectFunction;
```

And there's also `com.huawei.agconnect.function.FunctionRegistrar`, but I have no clue how to obtain an instance. Therefore the question is, how to import class [`AGConnectFunction`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/overview-0000001078324868)?

```
AGConnectFunction function = AGConnectFunction.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback, the team confirms that the codelab you mentioned will be updated in the near future.

`implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-function:1.6.2.300'`

[image]
It is recommended that you use this version to call cloud functions. For details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-cloudfunction-functioncall-0000001071314156).

Comment: This is correct. Some other dependencies were at `1.6.2.300`, but this one was still at `1.6.0.300`; must have missed that. For some reason Android Studio does not flag these packages as outdated - which may come from repository meta-data. If it would flag the packages as outdated, this might prevent subsequent issues; likely [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) repository index related.

Comment: The example should prevent unchecked assignment by adding `<>`: `new HashMap<>()`.